# How to run python commands when installed using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a `pyqt5` project which has a button. This button when clicks installs a windows service by using below command:

```
os.system('python myservice.py install')

os.system('python myservice.py start')
```

After this, a windows service `myservice` is installed and started. This is just one of the feature of whole application. I have now converted the project into `app.exe` using `pyinstaller`. Then using `inno compiler`, I have created a setup file.

I am installing the application on another system on which python is not installed. `pyinstaller` while converting the python scripts to exe, also binds the current python interpreter and installed packages so running the application on another pc works perfectly fine. But when I clicking on the install service buttons, its not working because it runs the command as `python myservice.py install` and because python is not installed thus it gives error.

I also checked this by typing python on cmd and it didnt showed anything. Is there any possibility where I can run python command without installing python on another pc. Thanks

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508677/accessing-python-interpreter-from-a-pyinstaller-bundle. I suppose you could pass values in `globals` or `locals`. I wouldn't normally recommend using [**`exec`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) but it does work. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253999/accessing-python-interpreter-from-a-pyinstaller-bundle-2

Comment: @PeterWood I want to run this command using pyinstaller `python myscript.py install`. I can do this `exec(open('opc_client_service.pyc').read())` but I am unable to understand how do I pass `install` to it.

Answer (score 1):

first of all I would recommend to use subprocess.call instead of os.system

second,
if you need to run another python code it is just fine to create another executable from myservice.py and then run `myservice.exe install`

alternative would be to have one code that generates service and UI in one compiled exe. But I do not think it is a good approach.

Comment: So running this command `myservice.exe install` will install the service.?

Comment: I would expect that software generated by pyinstaller will work the same way as py files themselves. So you need to create exe from myservice.py

Comment: @SAndrew, you need to check how `myservice.py` is created. This might be an arguments issue, since when you use command with python your arguments `install` is third one, while with .exe is second.